# Browserstack Automate: HTTP Basic Authentication on iOS

Tags: automated-tests, mobile-safari, basic-authentication, browserstack

I'm using a JavaScript/wdio based testing suite to test a website with BrowserStack Automate. A part of the pages that I'm testing requires HTTP Basic Authentication.

BrowserStack suggest in their [FAQ for the Screenshot API](https://www.browserstack.com/question/562) to use the following format:
http://username:password@www.xyz.com

While this works in some browsers, others like Safari on iOS seem not to support providing the credentials in the URL. I think it would be necessary to provide them as HTTP header.

Is there a way to get this working?

[image]

Comment: Execute it with appium version '1.16.0', it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in capabilities:

```
"safariIgnoreFraudWarning " : "true",
```

it worked for me for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that could help:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/basic-http-authentication#pass-username-and-password-in-the-url

It says that  Safari doesn't support basic authentication by passing the username and password in URL.

There is the way to do it with a `JavascriptExecutor`. I used it when BasicAuthentication popup apperared after submitting a form.

```
// here code that submits the form / clicks the link etc which brings you to basic auth
caps.setCapability("unhandledPromptBehavior", "ignore"); 
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("browserstack_executor: {\"action\": \"sendBasicAuth\", \"arguments\": {\"username\":\"<username>\", \"password\": \"<password>\", \"timeout\": \"<time in milliseconds>\"}}");
```

That worked for my case.